# How can I use identical model data in two different view models?

Tags: c#, mvvm, properties, view

I'm prototyping a WPF application making use of the MVVM pattern. The application shall have two windows: `MainWindow` and `LoginWindow`.

The `Model` contains two properties: `Username` and `Password`.

The `LoginWindow` is responsible for handling the username and password entered by the user, so the corresponding view model updates these properties. However, the `MainWindow` also needs access to the username and password for later usage with a client object.

How should I handle this?

Passing the instance of the `Model` created in the `LoginViewModel` to the `MainWindowViewModel`'s constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a Messenger/Event Aggregator.  An event aggregator is a broker object that you can take a reference to and specify what type of events you want to receive, without having to take a reference or even be aware of the objects generating the events.

Prism's EventAggregator is the most common one. See: [Event Aggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649187.aspx)

So:

ViewModel 1:

```
public ViewModel1(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
{
    _eventAggregator=eventAggregator;
}
private void SendMessage()
{
    _eventAggregator.GetEvent<UserLogin>().Publish(new UserLogin(_userName,_password);
}
```

ViewModel 2:

```
public ViewModel2(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
{
    _eventAggregator=eventAggregator;
    _eventAggregator.GetEvent<UserLogin>().Subscribe(UserLoginReceived,ThreadOption.BackgroundThread,true);
}

private void UserLoginReceived(UserLogin login)
{
  //do what you like here
}
```

What's happening is that the eventaggregator is passed to both the viewmodels.  ViewModel1 publishes a message but doesn't know who (if anyone) is listening to it.  ViewModel2 has subscribed to the event and is listening for a publisher to send it a message.

Using this approach you can have your viewmodels communicate without them taking references out on each other.